# How can I do a regular expression in Swift with binaries as a condition for pattern matching? For example, &HF040-&HF9FC, &H09, &H0A, &H0D, &H27, etc

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I want to do a regular expression conditional on the binary. Specifically, I want to use &HF040-&HF9FC, &H09,&H0A, &H0D, &H27 as conditions for I'd like to.

I couldn't pattern match a binary as a condition in Swift.

If there is someone who knows how to do it, I'd like to hear about it. If anyone knows how to do it, I'd appreciate it.

```swift
func pregMatche(text: String, pattern: String, options: NSRegularExpression.Options = []) -> Bool {
    guard let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: options) else {
        return false
    }
    let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, text.count))
    return matches.count > 0
}
pregMatche(text: "a", pattern: "0x61" ) //false
pregMatche(text: "0", pattern: "[0-9]") //true
```

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/Fqkk2H/1) help?You should use `pregMatche(text: "a", pattern: "\\U0061" ) //true`

Comment: thank you! do you know how to do that for &HF040-&HF9FC, &H09,&H0A, &H0D, &H27?

Comment: Can you please let me know what exactly are these codes?I mean are these hex codes or something else?

Comment: yes, these are hex codes. &HF040-&HF9FC are JIS Code, I think.

Comment: You can use something like `^[\uF040-\uF0FC\u0009\u000A\u000D\u0027]+$`

Comment: thank you so much, i try this!

Comment: If it works then I'll put as answer. please do let me know whether it worked.